Can i manipulate variable of class using its method
class example():
  id = 1
  def __init__(self, name):
     self.name = name

  def incr(self):
     my_id = id
     id += 1

  def info(self):
     print(self.name)

(global id) isn't working
I want this variable to increment everytime i use this method
Thanks
